# Five votes on any close vote close the question

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I voted [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20944/how-do-you-feel-in-fairy-tail-second-season?noredirect=1) question as opinion based but it was **put on hold as unclear what you're asking by..**. When I voted there were 3 vote on **unclear** and 1 vote on opinion. It looks the if the total number of votes is five then the question is put on hold with reason having higher vote. No body noticed it or the voting system is made in this way.

Comment: I believe it's made this way: the system will pick the close reason with the highest votes.

Comment: does not that mean if any one reason have 3 vote then just cast your vote on that reason,own reason does not matter

Comment: If a close reason has already received 3 or 4 votes, your vote is not going to change the fact that the question will be closed by the reason determined by the majority, unless you're a moderator. It has long been suggested to [distinguish close votes by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason), but it was never implemented.

Comment: This means majority is always right no matter what , but i liked the answer, yes never implemented and i think it will not be implemented looking from the date.

Answer (score 10):

As Gao points out in the comments, *all* users who voted to close a post are portrayed as having voted for the same reason as the majority (or, if a moderator closed the post, for the same reason as the moderator).

This is silly and I don't like it, but I have also seen no signs that this is likely to change anytime soon. If this bugs you, [head over to Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason) and upvote that feature request.

Comment: it do bugs me, just voting won't do anything, look at the timeline, it is long time , i don't think there will be any effect but voting is better then doing nothing

Comment: and Congratulation on your new position and responsibility , sorry for late wish, but wishing for good is never late :)